# Couldn't parse Json name with UUID()

Tags: model, uuid, swiftui, codable, swift5

i have next model for parse

```
struct Unicards: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
var id: String?
var title: String?
var info: String?
var brand: String?
var model: String?
var make_year: Int?
var message: String?
var message_color: String?
```

and I have a Json file in which there are many repeating arrays with different data sets, but with the same headers and sometimes repeating IDs

i want to use

```
var uuid = UUID()
```

to generate a unique ID for each data set and use the unique ID function

```
list (model, id: \ .uuid)
```

but when I add this line, I get an error

```
   "Thread 1: Fatal error: Couldn't parse" Json name ""
```

what I made a mistake, please tell me

I’ve looked through many answers already, but I can’t understand what exactly is my mistake.

tried

```
var uuid: UUID = UUID ()
```

and

```
var uuid = UUID (). uuidString
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your error is that by confirming to the `Codable` protocol it tries to synthesize the values, and as you are adding one that isn't there the decoder is getting confused.   To fix this, all you need to do is add a `CodingKeys` enum to your struct.

```
struct Unicards: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {

    var uuid: UUID = UUID()

    var id: String?
    var title: String?
    var info: String?
    var brand: String?
    var model: String?
    var make_year: Int?           // by convention this should be makeYear
    var message: String?
    var message_color: String?    // by convention this should be messageColor

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case title
        case info
        case brand
        case model
        case message
        case make_year
        case message_color

        // if you use the usual naming convention, you could swap these out
        // case makeYear = "make_year",
        // case messageColor = "message_color"
    }

}
```